# Get Attribute name using position from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, collections

I have the below XML in a data definitions file:

```
<PQTemplate documentID="CSTrlsEN" documentType="TransList" templateID="001" 
            templateType="Customer Copy" 
            templateName="C:\CPS\_templates\Mini-Statements\CSTrlsEN.doc">  
    <field pos="5" name="YPTME" descr="Time"  />
    <field pos="6" name="YPDTE" descr="Action Date"  />
    <field pos="7" name="YPBRNO" descr="Branch Number"  />
    <field pos="8" name="YPBNA" descr="Branch Name"  />
    <field pos="9" name="YPTID" descr="Teller ID"  />
    <field pos="10" name="YPISN" descr="Teller Sequence"  />
    <field pos="11" name="YPREF" descr="Customer Reference"  />
    <field pos="12" name="YPCUS" descr="Customer Name"  />
    <field pos="13" name="YPEAN" descr="Account Number"  />
    <field pos="14" name="YPATY" descr="Account Type"  />
    <field pos="15" name="YPCUR" descr="Currency"  />
    <field pos="16" name="YPBAL" descr="Available Balance"  />
</PQTemplate>
```

I want to build a data table by adding the columns named for the *name* attribute in the *field* sub-elements, but I am having trouble retrieving the information using LINQ:

Here is the code I am trying to write, I want to add a column name using the attribute names where the attribute *pos* is >5, so the first column will be **YPTME**, the second column will be **YPDTE**, and so on until the 12th and last column added will be **YPBAL**...

```
var mapInfo = from nm in XElement.Elements("PQTemplate").Elements("field")
                where (string)nm.Attribute("documentID") == sRequests[0] 
                select nm;

if (mapInfo != null)
{
    for (int iCol = 5; iCol < mapInfo.Count(); iCol++) 
    { 
        // there should be twelve
        string colName = mapInfo.Attributes(iCol);
        dt[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colName, typeof(System.String)));
    }
}
```

I seem unable to do this correctly, how can I do this and where am I going wrong with the line `string colName = mapInfo.Attributes(iCol);`

**EDIT:**

I also tried this, but again, cannot seem to apply the indexing in a `for..next` loop:

```
var mapInfo = from nm in XElement.Elements("PQTemplate").Elements("field")
            where (string)nm.Attribute("documentID") == sRequests[0] && Convert.ToInt32(nm.Attribute("pos").ToString())>=5 
            orderby Convert.ToInt32(nm.Attribute("pos").ToString())
            select nm;

if (mapInfo != null)
{
    for (int iDx=5; iDx<mapInfo.Count(); iDx++)
    {
    string colName=mapInfo[iDx];
    dt[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colName, typeof(System.String)));
            }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
        XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(stringXml);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (rootElement.Attribute("documentID").Value == "CSTrlsEN")
        {
             var colNames = from field in rootElement.Elements("field")
                          where Convert.ToInt32(field.Attribute("pos").Value) >= 5
                          select field.Attribute("name").Value;

             foreach (var name in colNames)
             {
                 dt.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
             }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add them to the datatable in order of the `pos` attribute...

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:-

```
 IEnumerable<string> columnNames = from nm in xdoc.Descendants("field")
                          where (string)nm.Parent.Attribute("documentID") == "CSTrlsEN"
                                              && (int)nm.Attribute("pos") >= 5
                          select (string)nm.Attribute("name");
```

Or if you want to do the validation for `documentID` you can use an if block before as suggested by @codeninja.

This will give you all the column Names with specified condition, then you can simply loop through it:-

```
 foreach (var colName in columnNames)
 {
     dt[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colName, typeof(System.String)));
 }
```

Comment: though it looks simple, you forced the user to validate documentID for every iteration. Its unwanted!!!

Comment: @codeninja - Agree with you although it will loop through each time we can skip the validation.